# DrawRect is out of view bounds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to draw a circular timer in a custom `UIView` like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
    min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = self.backgroundStrokeColor
    bgShapeLayer.fillColor = self.backgroundFillColor
    bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = self.backgroundLineWidth
    self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)        

    timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
        min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = self.timeLeftSrtokeColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = self.timeLeftFillColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = self.timeLeftLineWidth
    self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)        

    timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.midX-50 ,y: self.frame.midY-25, width: 100, height: 50))
    timeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    timeLabel.textAlignment = .center
    timeLabel.text = self.timeLeft.stringTime
    timeLabel.textColor = self.textColor
    timeLabel.font = self.textFont
    self.addSubview(timeLabel)

    strokeIt.toValue = 100 //From value is set in "startTimer(duration, timerProgress)
    strokeIt.duration = self.timeLeft
    // add the animation to your timeLeftShapeLayer
    timeLeftShapeLayer.add(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
    // define the future end time by adding the timeLeft to now Date() 
}
```

It works great on iPhone 6/7/X but on smaller iPhones (like 5/5s/SE) the timer is out of the view's bounds. Like this:

[![SE][1]][1]

How it should be (iPhone X):

[![X][2]][2]

I've tried to find out why for hours, but I haven't found anything :(

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks!
**Reinier Melian:**

[![Image][3]][3]

[![2][4]][4]

Note: The `timer` view is added programmatically to a superview called `container` that is added via `Interface Builder` and has `Clip To Bounds` enabled. The `container` is inside a `UITableViewCell`

Full code:

```
    public var backgroundStrokeColor: CGColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    public var backgroundFillColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    public var backgroundLineWidth: CGFloat = 15
    public var timeLeftSrtokeColor: CGColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    public var timeLeftFillColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    public var timeLeftLineWidth: CGFloat = 15
    public var textColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    public var textFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)

    fileprivate var timeLeft: TimeInterval = 0
    fileprivate var endDate: Date?
    fileprivate var timeLeftShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    fileprivate var bgShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    fileprivate var timeLabel:  UILabel?
    fileprivate var timer = Timer()
    fileprivate let strokeIt = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    //MARK: - UIView
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {    
        drawBgShape()
        drawTimeLeftShape()
        addTimeLabel()

        strokeIt.toValue = 1 //From value is set in "startTimer(duration, timerProgress)
        strokeIt.duration = self.timeLeft
        // add the animation to your timeLeftShapeLayer
        timeLeftShapeLayer?.add(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
        // define the future end time by adding the timeLeft to now Date()

    }

    //MARK: - Public
    public func startTimer(duration: TimeInterval, timerProgress: Int) {
        self.timeLeft = duration
        endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(timeLeft)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        strokeIt.fromValue = timerProgress
    }

    //MARK: - Private
    fileprivate func drawBgShape() {
        //we initialize and add the layer only if there is not initialized
        if(bgShapeLayer == nil){
            bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer!)
        }

        bgShapeLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        bgShapeLayer?.strokeColor = self.backgroundStrokeColor
        bgShapeLayer?.fillColor = self.backgroundFillColor
        bgShapeLayer?.lineWidth = self.backgroundLineWidth
    }

    fileprivate func drawTimeLeftShape() {
        //we initialize and add the layer only if there is not initialized
        if(timeLeftShapeLayer == nil){
            timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer!)
        }
        timeLeftShapeLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        timeLeftShapeLayer?.strokeColor = self.timeLeftSrtokeColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer?.fillColor = self.timeLeftFillColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer?.lineWidth = self.timeLeftLineWidth
    }

    fileprivate func addTimeLabel() {
        //we initialize and add the UILabel only if there is not initialized
        if(timeLabel == nil){
            timeLabel = UILabel()
            self.addSubview(timeLabel!)
        }

        timeLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX-50 ,y: self.frame.midY-25, width: 100, height: 50)
        timeLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        timeLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        timeLabel?.text = self.timeLeft.stringTime
        timeLabel?.textColor = self.textColor
        timeLabel?.font = self.textFont
    }

    //MARK: - Actions
    @objc fileprivate func updateTime() {
        if timeLeft > 0 {
            timeLeft = endDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? 0
            timeLabel?.text = self.timeLeft.stringTime
        } else {
            timeLabel?.text = self.timeLeft.stringTime
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

**UITableViewCell Code:**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let countDownTimer = CountDownTimer(frame: self.countDownTimerContainer.frame)
    countDownTimer.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
    countDownTimer.frame = self.countDownTimerContainer.bounds
    let secondsUntilEndDate = abs(self.timerEndDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)//abs = absolute value (-x to x)
    countDownTimer.startTimer(duration: secondsUntilEndDate, timerProgress: self.timerProgress)

    self.countDownTimerContainer.addSubview(countDownTimer)
        self.countDownTimerContainer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: add timeLeftShapeLayer.frame = self.bounds

Comment: and I think you need to check if your timeLeftShapeLayer is already added

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've tried to add this line as the first of `drawRect`, but I can't see any difference...

Comment: add self.layer.borderWidth = 1 and self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor and post the image in an small device

Comment: can u share a demo ????

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you, updated my question with an image

Comment: @Sh_Khan What do you mean?

Comment: its seems that your view is clipped for some reason @FS.O6

Comment: did you add the border to your UIView or to a sublayer? @FS.O6

Comment: @ReinierMelian To the `self.layer`. Please see the note I've added to the question to make it clearer

Comment: seems to be a problem with your timerView frame, did you add constraints or you handle the frame manually? @FS.O6

Comment: can you add container.layer.borderWidth = 1 and self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor and post the image? @FS.O6

Comment: @ReinierMelian To the `container` I've added constraints. To the `timerView` I've set the frame to `container.frame` and then set the `timerView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero`

Comment: @ReinierMelian Added. Please take a look. Thank you!!

Comment: your issue is related to viewDidLayoutSubview, override that implementation in the viewController and add container.needsDisplay() and set the frame of timerView = container.bounds @FS.O6

Comment: @ReinierMelian The `container` is inside a `UITableViewCell` so I don't have a `viewDidLayoutSubview`

Comment: then inside of `layoutSubViews` method add first `timerView.frame =  container.bounds` and after that call `container.setNeedsDisplay()` @FS.O6

Comment: you need to override layoutSubViews method of your cell @FS.O6

Comment: @ReinierMelian Now the timer is added twice... Even in iPhone X

Comment: but the other problem was fixed @FS.O6?

Comment: @ReinierMelian It's added twice, once like it should be and another time out of bounds

Comment: OK i Will post the final answer @FS.O6

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you

Comment: @FS.O6 check my answer with the updated draw method and let me know if works as should

Comment: @ReinierMelian I still get a duplicated timer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to readjust the frame of your `containerView` in your cell `layoutSubViews` method

```
func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    timerView.frame = container.bounds
    containerView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

and after a little adjust in your original method

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    //we initialize and add the layer only if there is not initialized
    if(bgShapeLayer == nil){
       bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)  
    }

    bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
    min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = self.backgroundStrokeColor
    bgShapeLayer.fillColor = self.backgroundFillColor
    bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = self.backgroundLineWidth

       //we initialize and add the layer only if there is not initialized
    if(timeLeftShapeLayer == nil){
       timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)  
    }
    timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
        min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = self.timeLeftSrtokeColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = self.timeLeftFillColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = self.timeLeftLineWidth     

       //we initialize and add the UILabel only if there is not initialized
    if(timeLabel == nil){
       timeLabel = timeLabel()
       self.addSubview(timeLabel)
    }
    timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX-50 ,y: self.frame.midY-25, width: 100, height: 50)
    timeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    timeLabel.textAlignment = .center
    timeLabel.text = self.timeLeft.stringTime
    timeLabel.textColor = self.textColor
    timeLabel.font = self.textFont

    strokeIt.toValue = 100 //From value is set in "startTimer(duration, timerProgress)
    strokeIt.duration = self.timeLeft
    // add the animation to your timeLeftShapeLayer
    timeLeftShapeLayer.add(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
    // define the future end time by adding the timeLeft to now Date() 
}
```

## Change your Cell Code for this one

**add CountDownTimer as var in your cell**

```
var timerView :  CountDownTimer?
```

**modify your layoutSubviews method**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if(self.timerView == nil) {
        self.timerView = CountDownTimer(frame: self.countDownTimerContainer.bounds)
        self.countDownTimerContainer.addSubview(countDownTimer)
    }

    countDownTimer.frame = self.countDownTimerContainer.bounds
    let secondsUntilEndDate = abs(self.timerEndDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)//abs = absolute value (-x to x)
    countDownTimer.startTimer(duration: secondsUntilEndDate, timerProgress: self.timerProgress)
    self.countDownTimerContainer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: I still get the timer duplicated

Comment: you must remove any previous initialization of the layers and the UILabel @FS.O6

Comment: What do you mean? Where?

Comment: can you post your current full implementation of timerView ? @FS.O6

Comment: Added. Please take a look

Comment: and with this implementation you are getting duplicated the TimerView? @FS.O6

Comment: where you add your timerView to the containerView? @FS.O6 there should be the problem

Comment: I've added the code from the `UITableViewCell`. Please take a look

Comment: there is the problem I will add the fixed version for you @FS.O6

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know when you added